# Reading in the output of a program, saving it as a string, and using that string in the original program

Tags: c, string, file-io, cygwin

I am using trying to get specific information from a group of MP3 files, currently I am in the main cygwin64 that holds MP3 files and a .C file which simply contains

```
FILE * fp;
```

It contains that single line of code because when that line of code is in place and I type and run "thing.c" in the cygwin command line it outputs what seems the be the information of the contents of the folder. For example it outputs,

```
home:                                                      sticky, directory
lib:                                                       directory
sbin:                                                      directory
setup-x86_64.exe:                                          PE32+ executable       (GUI) x86-64 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows
song.mp3:                                                  Audio file with     ID3 version 2.3.0, contains: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 128 kbps, 44.1 kHz,     JntStereo
song1.mp3:                                                 Audio file with   ID3 version 2.3.0, contains: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 128 kbps, 44.1 kHz,   JntStereo
thing.c:                                                   ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
thing.txt:                                                 empty
```

What I want to do is be able to pull that output into a string that I can then use in my C file and alter and then re print out the new altered information. However I'm not sure where the output really is coming from or how I might be able to get it or save the output as a .txt file or back into a C file.
Any advice is appreciated Thanks!

Comment: This question makes very little sense. In order for thing.c to do anything meaningful, it needs to have more than one line, a main function and a way to compile the file into an executable.

Answer (score 0):

This file is not really a C file at all.  Because you're in Cygwin, you're likely operating on a case-insensitive filesystem (NTFS).  As such, Cygwin's `file` command is running when you run the `.c` file.  The way you've attempted to declare a variable (apparently) just so happens to be doing a 'file * fp' command.  I'm sure you're getting `fp: Cannot open "fp"` or something similar after the rest of your output.

This is not anything C-related at all but is just being interpreted as a script by your shell.

It sounds like you have a lot to learn if you want to do this in C.  More likely, you can probably write a shell script to accomplish what you want.  While I've never used it, `mp3info` (https://github.com/jaalto/cygwin-package--mp3info) exists for pulling tag information from MP3 files.  You could possibly get the exact information you want from that, or pipe the output into `sed`, `awk`, or a number of other tools.